# Killing shell processes when thread dies

Tags: ruby

I have code like this:

```rb
#! /usr/bin/env ruby

Thread.report_on_exception=false
Thread.abort_on_exception=true

Thread.new do
  `shellcommand 1 2 3`
end

do_other_stuff
```

If `do_other_stuff` encounters an exception, it kills the thread and the whole ruby process, which is what I want. But, `shellcommand 1 2 3` continues running in the background.

How can I have `shellcommand 1 2 3` also be killed when the ruby process aborts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't (with a general flag on `Thread` at least). It's a separate process that you started in a thread. The thread dying doesn't stop the process.

You have to save the pid of the process and terminate it explicitly:

```
Thread.report_on_exception = false
Thread.abort_on_exception = true

pids = []

at_exit do
  pids.each do |pid|
    `kill -9 #{pid}`
  end
end

Thread.new do
  pids.push Process.spawn('for((i=0; ;++i)); do echo "$i"; sleep 1; done')
end

sleep 5
raise 'Failure'
```

Output:

```
0
1
2
3
4
Traceback (most recent call last):
test.rb:17:in `<main>': Failure (RuntimeError)
```

Needless to say, don't use this code as is in production.